# Boxcutter cutting function creates a lattice/lattice modifier I don't want, how to fix?

Tags: modeling

[image]

How do I just get the cutting function without this lattice thing appearing? Thanks

Comment: That's not a lattice modifier. It's the bounding box of the cutter object! As with Blender's own boolean addon, Boxcutter sets the visibility mode of the cutter object to Bounds rather than Textured. Look at the Viewport Display section of the cutter's properties and you'll see it's set to Bounds whereas the object that's been cut is still set to Textured. If you don't want to see it just select the cutter and hide it with the 'H' key.

Answer (score 0):

In the Keep Modifiers section turn the lattice on and it will work like you expect.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fix the problem by deleting the configuration file and then restarting blender. However, you will have to add your preferences again. Go to appdata>roaming> Blender foundation> 3.0 then delete the configuration file. Im not sure about the file path.